# laravel ajax method:'post' but It send http request with get

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

use ajax for laravel 4.x ,
code

```
 $('#button').click(function(e){  
        $.ajax({   
           method:'post',  
           url:'test',
           data:datas,//exists
           success:function(data){  
           }, 
        }); 
    });
```

but i found it send http request with get,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('#button').click(function(e){  
        $.ajax({   
           type:'post',  
           url:'test',
           data:datas,//exists
           success:function(data){  
           }, 
        }); 
    });
```

(Note that method is replaced by type)